# using props to show child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

i want to show my child component, but it give me error in browser
`[Vue warn]: Property "modules" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.`

i have parent component that i use props to send boolean value to child component;

**parent component**

```html
<template>
  // i am tring to props visible value here
  <SlidePage :visible="showForm"></SlidePage>

  // i am tring to change value of showForm
  <button label="hide manufacturer" @click="showForm = true">Show</button>

</template>


<script setup>
import SlidePage from '@/components/parts/storypage/SlidePage.vue'

import { ref } from 'vue'

const showForm = ref(false)

</script>
```

**child component**

```html
<template>
    // get the cisible from props
    <div class="modal" v-if="visible">
        <p class="title has-text-white">Modal title</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const props = defineProps({
  visible: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
})
```

Comment: Your shared code looks fine, I think the issue is somewhere else

Comment: yes,, but i dont know it doesnt work to show child component. I use router, does it influence?

Comment: I did not see any use of `modules` in your code. Looks like posted code is not complete.

Comment: yes,,i found the error is not in  the topic that i ask. Thanks all its done

Answer (score -1):

you cannot send props from parent to child component. You can use `provide()` function to pass value to child component and `inject()` to receive the value that you want to pass. details https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#prop-drilling

Comment: From where do you know *you cannot send props from parent to child component*? your answer is misleading.